# The getter 'length' was called on null. fetch from api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from api  its splash screen of my app I  want user wait 5 second when app is launched and then go to next screen but when I tried fetch data from api I received The getter 'length' was called on null. please help me here is my code I tried  resolve it number of other resources but failed to find solution that's why I am posting my question is here please check and help

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/main.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new SplashScreen(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/MyHomePage': (BuildContext context) => new MyHomePage()
    },
  ));
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 5);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/MyHomePage');
  }
  bool _loading=true;
  Map data;
  List userData=null;
  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("https://livinghopemobile.com/public/api/fetch-site-settings?token=123ab_@_@AbCD");
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.body);
    setState(() {
      userData = data["data"];
      _loading=false;
      // print(userData[0]['title']);
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //startTime();
    getData();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount:userData.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

return Container(
  child: Image.network(userData[index]['site_logo']),
);
          }

      )

      );

  }
}

Launching lib/ui/SplashScreen.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           23.8s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60469/bL7bmRYyhoc=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SplashScreen(dirty, state: _SplashScreenState#5fa75):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SplashScreen file:///Users/apple/livinghopev4/livinghope4ios/lib/ui/SplashScreen.dart:10:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _SplashScreenState.build (package:flutter_app/ui/SplashScreen.dart:61:30)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: {"status":200,"message":"Data fetched successfully","data":{"id":1,"site_logo":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/site_logo\/270421_122025_image.png","site_name":"Living hope","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2021-04-27T07:20:26.000000Z"}}
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
#0      _SplashScreenState.getData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_app/ui/SplashScreen.dart:41:7)
#1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1267:30)
#2      _SplashScreenState.getData (package:flutter_app/ui/SplashScreen.dart:40:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: try ```List userData=[];``` instead of ```List userData=null;```

Answer (score 0):

This is because data is not type List, and userData is null hence there is no length to it when you are calling userData.length in ListView.builder.

Change null to [].

```
{"status":200,"message":"Data fetched successfully","data":{"id":1,"site_logo":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/site_logo\/270421_122025_image.png","site_name":"Living hope","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2021-04-27T07:20:26.000000Z"}}
```

You could append the received data to userData, like: `userData.add(data)`.

Comment: how fetch site_logo in my app ?

Comment: Ill create an object for the response and call from there.

Answer (score 0):

You try it:

```
itemCount:userData.length == null ? 0 : userData.length
```

Comment: You can use double `??` like this: `itemCount: userData.length ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

Data is returning in Object and you are taking it as List. This is the reason you are getting the error.

Solution:
Don't use Listview.builder as api response is just an object(Map<String, dynamic>).

You can simply use

```
Image.network(userData['site_logo']),
```

and everthing will be fine.